# wso2 api manager 3.2.0 OAuth2Service Provided Callback URL does not match with the provided one error?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I faced with following exception when try to login publisher:

in browser :

```
Registered callback does not match with the provided url.
```

in console :

```
OAuth2Service Provided Callback URL does not match with the provided one.
```

deployment.toml

```
[server]
hostname = "172.25.129.67"
node_ip = "172.25.129.67"
#offset=0
mode = "single" #single or ha
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"
```

in service provider

```
regexp=(https://172.25.129.67:9443/devportal/services/auth/callback/login|https://172.25.129.67:9443/devportal/services/auth/callback/logout)
```

Could you please help me to solve it?

Comment: Are you accessing the Portals with the same IP address that is mentioned? Or are you accessing the portals with any other hostnames?

Comment: Thanks, I changed node ip and hostname as following and it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I changed as following and it fixed.

```
[server]
hostname = "172.25.129.67"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
```